# Shell script echo outputting arguments

Tags: bash, shell, socat

I'm currently trying to build a shell script that sends broadcast UDP packets. My problem is that my echo is outputting the arguments instead, and I have no ideia why. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script
var1="\xdd\x02\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x10\x46\x44\x30\x30\x37\x33\x45\x31\x39\x39\x45\x43\x31\x42\x39\x34\x00"
var2="\xdd\x00\x0a\x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02"

echo -ne $var1 | socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:5050,broadcast
echo -ne $var2 | socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:5050,broadcast
```

Using wireshark I can see the script is printing -ne as characters and also is not converting each \xHH to the correspondant ASCII character.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured my problem out. It turns out I was runninc my script with sh ./script.sh instead of bash ./script.sh

Comment: that is strange. "sh" is typically an alias to "bash" on Linux. What does "type sh" says?

Comment: @toddlermenot That is "typically" true on some distros, but not on others. Even then, Bash behaves differently when invoked as `sh`. You really should never expect `sh` to run Bash, even if that might be how it's implemented at this point in time on your particular configuration. See also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 0):

`echo` implementations are hopelessly inconsistent about whether they take command options (like `-ne`) or simply treat them as part of the string to print, and/or whether they interpret escape sequences in the strings to print. It sounds like you're seeing a difference between bash's builtin version of `echo` vs. (I'm guessing) the version in /bin/echo. I've also seen it vary even between different versions of bash.

If you want consistent behavior for anything nontrivial, use `printf` instead of `echo`. It's slightly more complicated to use it correctly, but IMO worth it because your scripts won't randomly break because `echo` changed for whatever reason. The tricky thing about `printf` is that the first argument is special -- it's a format string in which all escape sequences are interpreted, and any `%` sequences tell it how to add in the rest of the arguments. Also, it doesn't add a linefeed at the end unless you specifically tell it to. In this case, you can just give it the hex codes in the format string:

```
printf "$var1" | socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:5050,broadcast
printf "$var2" | socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:5050,broadcast
```